# Youtube javascript embed appears cut off in Fire TV Stick Gen2 and 4K version

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, amazon-fire-tv

I am developing an Android app for Amazon Fire Stick devices. I am using Cordova to create the Android wrapper around my web application which is loaded in an iframe. I am using javascript to embed youtube player as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Below is what my code to embed Youtube looks like:

```
var player = new YT.Player('youtube_container', {
    height: 720,
    width: 1280,
    videoId: 'some_video_id',
    playerVars: {
        autohide: 1,
        controls: 0,
        enablejsapi: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showinfo: 0
    },
    events: {
        'onReady': function () {
            player.seekTo(0, true);
            player.playVideo();
        },
    }
});
```

I have used this code to embed youtube videos in my web application for a long time now and it works without any problem but in Fire Stick devices the video shows up cut off as shown below.
[image: Video cut off].

The video is supposed to play in the rectangular section. The video does play but only the top left corner seems to be visible.

The strange thing is, it plays fine if I play it in full screen mode. It also plays fine in Fire Tablet devices whether it's full screen or not. Also, in my tests, I have found that the video is positioned correctly in the iframe in some rare occassions.

It seems similar to the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289848/embedded-youtube-player-getting-cut-off), but no answer is marked correct and it has been 5 years since. I'm hoping someone has fixed this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: edited width and height value to reflect my actual code i.e. landscape

Comment: `height` and `width` look backwards to me, unless you have a tall narrow video.

Comment: If I open the web app iframe in a browser the video plays just fine. And in rare occasions the video is positioned correctly even in Fire TV Stick. Also the same application (apk) show videos fine in Fire Tablet.

Comment: Did you try it the other way?

Comment: Do you mean switching height and width? I did try that. When I do that the video does not play at all. It just shows empty box with black background.

Comment: Try `width:720, height:405` instead. That would be 16 x 9, based on the width you want.

Comment: With the dimensions you mentioned it looks like this,( https://imgur.com/a/lrLaopo ). The box in the middle is a small cut off section of the actual video. Whereas standard dimensions like 1600 X 900, 1280 X 720, 1920 X 1080 loads as the screenshot in my post.